# Removing all the characters from a string after pattern+2

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove all the characters from a string after a specific pattern +2 in bash.

In this case I have for example:

```
3434.586909
3434.58690932454
3434.5869093232r3353
```

I'd like to keep just 3434.58

I tried with awk and a wildcard but my test haven't worked yet.

Comment: Please clarify which is the specific pattern and please post what you tried even if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(\...\).*/\1/'
```

It means "remembering a dot and two following characters, replace them and everything that follows with the remembered part".

Answer (score 0):

How about using floating point logic?

```
awk '{printf("%.02f\n",$0)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Porcac1x, Could you please do let me know if this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,7)}' file 

3434.58
3434.58
3434.58
```